# Guard Customization in Laravel for Custom Authentication

Tags: php, laravel

I have gone through the Laravel documentation for the custom authentication. And I studied about the Guard Authentication as:

**Guard Customization**
You may also customize the "guard" that is used to authenticate and register users. To get started, define a guard method on your LoginController, RegisterController, and  ResetPasswordController. The method should return a guard instance:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

protected function guard()
{
    return Auth::guard('guard-name');
}
```

The above part is from the Laravel documentation. I have developed the CRUD operation project and this operation should be done by the admin level users only. For this, I thought guard customization would be better option. In the above case what does 'guard-name' here? Is it the name of the users who are given the admin level authority?

There is also scenario that the admin can assign the authority of the admin to other users. Due to lack of the detail explanation in the Laravel documentation I couldn't figure out how can I use guard for the above case. What can be other better option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`guard-name` is the name of your custom guard. There is also a full example on how to add your own guard (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#adding-custom-guards).

Guards are there to define different authentication methods (e.g. session- or token-based). For me it sounds like you are looking for gates and policies in Laravel. With those you can authorize an user against a given resource.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization

When using policies you can define filters. This filters will be called before any other method on the policy. So with an `before` filter you could check if the user is admin.

```
public function before($user, $ability)
{
    if ($user->isSuperAdmin()) {
        return true;
    }
}
```